# Keep receiving Bad Request when using passport-ldap

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, ldap, passport.js

I'm having a problem with using passport-ldap. I just can't seem to get anything other than Bad Request. I've got scripts working in Python and Bash, so I know the information is correct and maybe I'm just not seeing something. Any help would be great.

Here's a condensed version with just the bits necessary.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

var ldapOptions = {
 server: { 
 url: <URL>,
 bindDN: 'uid=<username>',
 bindCredentials: '<password>',
 searchBase: 'ou=Users, ou=Internal, o=<Corporate>,
 searchAttributes: ['uid', 'mail', 'displayName'],
 searchFilter: 'uid={{username}}'
 }
}

passport.use('ldapauth', new LdapStrategy(ldapOptions));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}), function(req, res) {
 console.log('Hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in router.post, you cannon handle for a request without sand back something.
try res.send('somethings');

Best regards

Comment: It still returns Bad Request